# Allow Only Standard Subscriptions in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

does anyone know if there is a way to allow users creating standard SSRS subscriptions but disallow data driven subscriptions?

The end goal is to provide self service subscriptions to non technical users and to prevent havoc that could be brought on by running or validating ill designed SQL scripts in the data set that drives the data driven subscription.

Found that data driven subscriptions are allowed in specific versions of SQL Server so thought there is a switch to disallow data driven subscriptions through roles...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

SSRS [standard edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016) doesn't support "data driven subscriptions"
The SSRS edition can be different to the SQL Server Engine edition.

That is, use SSRS standard edition for your end users and the feature simply won't exist.

In the SSRS permission model, you can't separate permissions for subscriptions and "data driven subscriptions". it is just "[Manage subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/subscriptions-and-delivery-reporting-services)"